# Deleting from table if check box unticked

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

This is probably an easy one but I am stuck. I have a form with checkboxes that show employees and there skills, these are taken from a table with a many to many relationship.
The below code works for updating the records but I am unsure on how to delete records if the checkbox is un-checked

```
$emp=$_POST['emp'];  

if(isset($_POST['chk1'])){
    $checkbox=$_POST['chk1'];
    $arr_num=count($checkbox);
    $i=0;

    while ($i < $arr_num)
    {
        $qry = "INSERT IGNORE INTO skillsets (skill_id, empr_id )VALUES(?, ?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $checkbox[$i], $emp);
        $stmt->execute();
        $i++;
    }
}
 else .... delete from .....
```

I am not sure of the syntax for the `else`, can someone help me out?

Comment: Title says DELETE, but you are using INSERT, what are you missing?

Comment: Euhm that should do it right? The 

else{

//DELETE

}

Comment: Insert is working fine its the DELETE part I am having trouble with as the unchecked boxes are not posting the skill_id of the checkbox, how can I delete it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can define hidden inputs for every checkbox (before it) with the same name. Eg.

```
<input type="hidden" name="items[1]" value="no" />
<input type="checkbox" name="items[1]" value="yes" />
```

`1` is your item ID.
And now if checkbox is checked then its value will be send. In other case, value from hidden field will be send to your server. With this data you can iterate through `items` array, get ID from index and check value to know if it's checked or not.

Comment: I cant to this because I am not updating true false type entries, the value submitted from the form when checked is the skill_id , then I insert that id along with the emp id into the many to many linked table

Comment: @Darkside So you can put value of each `skill_id` in place of `1`, iterate though `items`, and insert or delete depending on received value (`yes`, or `no`).

Comment: Probably not the most ideal way but I have it working by deleting all records for posted emp_id then doing the update for that id.